How to use array inside choice_label of Symfony form?
I want to use array in choice_label. For example, I have a text below (which has several lines) ($categories->getSubCategory()) and a subCategory is inserted in each line, and I want $categories->getMainCategory() . ' > ' . $sub to be displayed for each line in list:
$builder
->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => $category ?? null,
                'class' => Categories::class,
                'choice_label' => function (Categories $categories, string $key): string {
                    $subReplace = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $categories->getSubCategory());
                    $subExplode = explode("\n", $subReplace);
                    foreach ($subExplode as $sub) {
                        $category = $categories->getMainCategory() . ' > ' . $sub;
            return $category;
                    }
                },
                'autocomplete' => true
            ])

But how should I do this?
